# retransmit mutlicast package with added XML data

Tags: python, xml, listener, multicast, forward

I have an application that only listening and working with multicast-IP-Packages with XML content (maybe just need a XML header)

Is there a python function to listen on specific multicast-address:port and adding XML content and then just forward/retrans this on the same or different mc:port with added XML data, so my application listen to that package?